# Calculate the time difference of the two columns stored in string format

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50ed90a55502684f440001ac"),
    "time" : "2020-05-14T14:12:46.058-0400",
    "ServerTimeStamp" : "2020-05-14T14:12:46.058-0400"

}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50ed90a55502684f440001ad"),
    "time" : "2020-05-14T15:12:46.058-0400",
    "ServerTimeStamp" : "2020-05-14T14:12:46.058-0400"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50ed90a55502684f440001ae"),
    "time" : "2020-05-14T18:12:46.058-0400",
    "ServerTimeStamp" :"2020-05-14T14:12:46.058-0400"
}
```

I would like to calculate the time difference of above columns : time and ServerTimeStamp ( in seconds) as below . here the time field is in string format instead of datetime

```
{

    "_id" : ObjectId("50ed90a55502684f440001ac"),
    "time" : "2020-05-14T14:12:46.058-0400",
   v"ServerTimeStamp" : "2020-05-14T14:12:46.058-0400",
    "time_difference" :0
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50ed90a55502684f440001ad"),
    "time" : "2020-05-14T15:12:46.058-0400",
     "ServerTimeStamp" : "2020-05-14T14:12:46.058-0400"
    "time_difference" : 3600  
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50ed90a55502684f440001ae"),
    "time" : "2020-05-14T18:12:46.058-0400",
    "ServerTimeStamp" : "2020-05-14T14:12:46.058-0400"
    "time_difference" : 10800
}
```

I tried the below query but getting error and i have already converted the time to date from string

```
db.hello.aggregate([
  {
      $project:{duration : {

           $divide: [{$subtract: 
          [  $StringToDate:("$time") ,$StringToDate:("$ServerTimeStamp") ]

          },3600000]
          }
  }}
])
```

Comment: I don't think there is `$StringToDate` operator in MongoDB, and it looks like an invalid syntax

Comment: I noticed you asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61825682/need-to-calculate-the-datetime-difference-for-the-datetime-field-saved-in-string) earlier as well. What's wrong with that question? Why do you think this one need to be posted separately?

Comment: from your output, I guess you need to use the previous record to calculate the time difference right? Not the current record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use the built in [`$toDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) operator, available from MongoDB v4.0

```
db.hello.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: { // use $addFields to add new fields while keeping previous fields
      duration : {
        $divide: [
          {
            $subtract: [
              { $toDate: "$time" },
              { $toDate: "$ServerTimeStamp" }
            ]
          },
          1000 // the result was in millisecond, if you want in seconds you have to divide by 1000, if you want in hours divide by 3600000
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

For earlier MongoDB versions, there is [`$dateFromString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) operator, available from MongoDB v3.6

```
db.hello.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: { // use $addFields to add new fields while keeping previous fields
      duration : {
        $divide: [
          {
            $subtract: [
              { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$time" } },
              { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$ServerTimeStamp" } }
            ]
          },
          1000 // the result was in millisecond, if you want in seconds you have to divide by 1000, if you want in hours divide by 3600000
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: You can also use the [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/index.html) to convert the string value to a `date` object - this has a shorter syntax.

Comment: @prasad_ nice suggestion, I have added as an alternative